# Spring boot does not work in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, gradle

I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/), but my application won't run on tomcat. Than I tried to deploy the sample application:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-convert-jar-to-war
cd gs-convert-jar-to-war/complete
gs-convert-jar-to-war/complete> ./gradlew build
cp gs-convert-jar-to-war/complete/build/libs/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0.war webapps
```

at catalina log:

```
Aug 27, 2014 3:00:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/richard/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0.war
```

localhost:8080/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0/ -> 404 error :(

So the sample application doesn't work like my application. I don't get any error message, or anything else, that's all.

I'm running the stack on apache-tomcat-7.0.52, Java 1.8.0_05, GNU/Linux x86_64.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It looks like your file is still in the war.  It should have run the war file.  You should see assets and WEB-INF when you go into the file.  Did you run the war yet?

Comment: Are You sure about context path?

Comment: Looks like we're having the same bad day! In my case, when I built  the tutorial project with Java 1.8.0_20, the resulting war file would not work. But if I built the project with Java 1.7, the war file works fine.

Comment: There's a Spring Boot issue open for this where we're also trying to figure out what's going on: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1464. There should be another INFO log line stating the deployment has completed. What, if anything, is logged between the lines you've already posted and the completed line? It would also be helpful to know what's in your war file that's been built by Gradle. Could you update your question with the result of running `unzip -l` on the war?

Comment: My apologies, it looks like I'm having different problem. I ran my tomcat with JRE_HOME still pointing to jdk1.7. After I changed my JRE_HOME to jdk1.8, the issue's gone.